# django admin overriding delete_model not working with bulk delete

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to disable deleting for a specific model instance

I overrided `delete_model` in the `ModelAdmin` as follows :

```
def delete_model(self, request, client):
    if client.schema_name == 'public':
        messages.set_level(request, messages.ERROR)
        messages.error(request, 'Suppression interdite pour la racine')
    else:
        super().delete_model(request, client)
```

It works when I click the delete button on change view

[image][image]

But not with bulk delete as the instance is deleted without preventing

[image]

How can I fix this ? I also realized that `delete_model` is not called with bulk delete which makes a bit weird.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As bulk delete admin action [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/actions/) already warns you

> The “delete selected objects” action uses QuerySet.delete() for
> efficiency reasons, which has an important caveat: **your model’s
> delete() method will not be called.**
>
> If you wish to override this behavior, you can override
> ModelAdmin.delete_queryset() or write a custom action which does
> deletion in your preferred manner – for example, by calling
> Model.delete() for each of the selected items.
>
> For more background on bulk deletion, see the documentation on object
> deletion.